# This code keeps on returning 0 instead of increasing in size?

Tags: java, arraylist

What I am trying to do is:

Prompt the user for a list size (e.g., N = 10,000). Create an ArrayList of the Integers from 1 to N, in random order.

This is what I have so far, but the list just returns the number 0 n times

```
System.out.print("Please enter a list size: ");
       Scanner ST = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n= ST.nextInt();
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
        for ( int i = 1; i<(n+1); i++){
            int k = 0;
            k = k + 1;
            myList.add(k);

        }
```

Comment: After this step I also need help on calling Collections.shuffle onto the list. How would I create the statement to call Collections.shuffle onto this list?

Comment: tip: on this, and your previous question, when you have been given a correct/helpful example be sure to check it as answered.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, because you're declaring `k` *inside* the loop. Just move

```
int k = 0;
```

to *before* the loop. Currently the "newly declared" variable will be assigned the value of 0 on the first line of each iteration of the loop; it will then be incremented to 1 on the next line. Then that value (1) will be boxed and the return value `Integer.valueOf(1)` will be added to the list. Then we go round again...

An alternative is to just use the loop index - potentially changing the loop to a rather more idiomatic style at the same time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    myList.add(i + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!After this step I also need help on calling Collections.shuffle onto the list. Do you know how would I create the statement to call Collections.shuffle onto this list?

Comment: @KarthikPatil: It's just a static method call: `Collections.shuffle(myList);`. Which bit of this was causing you trouble?